# useSelector causing rerender despite using shallowEqual?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple App Component as below

```js
import { useSelector, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  console.log('im at App')
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => (state.userManagement.user), shallowEqual);
  // user is an object

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Hello World
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Whenever I press on "Home" `Link` and navigate to the component above, I will see **Im at App** twice? `useSelector` will cause a second re-render despite I've added `shallowEqual`. Have I understood the concept of using this `shallowEqual` wrongly?

**UPDATES:**

I've added the suggested `useEffect` to debug and realized that it was being logged one time, but why `im at App` is being printed twice?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current user changed", currentUser)
  },[currentUser])
```

[image]

Comment: Is your app in rendered in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)?

Comment: @HMR: Yes it is! Wondering if that's the reason?

Comment: @HMR: I just commented `strictmode` and it does solve the problem! Can you please post an answer with some explanation on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks/renders can be run multiple times when in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Comment: I don't really get it, I did ran thru the docs about strict mode but I don't see why it impacted `useSelector` hooks

Comment: @Isaac It mounts components twice sometimes to see if there is a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it here as suggestion requires some code.

Just try this out to debug it. If this log is happening, it means your currentUser object is changing

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("current user changed", currentUser)
},[currentUser])
```

Note: This is just suggestion to debug it.

Comment: Hi I've added the code and it's being printed once, meaning indeed `currentUser` did not changed

Comment: Can you paste the component code which renders APp itself

Comment: I mean, there can be other reasons , Why your app is rerendering again. Mainly if any of the above components which is rerendering itself

Answer (score -1):

If you look into the implementation of `useSelector` (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L9) then you will find, that `useSelector` will not only check if the return value changes, but also if there are any changes inside the store (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L32).

It will by design force an update by dispatching a state update (see implementation of `forceRender`: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L15)

As much as I like the react hooks, it feels like it might be better to use the `connect(mapStateToProps)(App)` approach in order to avoid too many updates.

Would be interesting to understand why they implemented it in that way.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the behavior of `useSelector`.  React will double-render components in `<StrictMode>` to catch bugs, so the log statement is running twice.

Comment: @markerikson: Thanks for your explanation now I get it, thanks!